# When I press the "All" checkbox" I don't get any data. What have I done wrong here?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a table and the table has a column called status. Basically, this status can be in progress, pending or dispensed.

[image: Image of table]

So when I check one of the checkboxes that are above the table, I get the data related to the checkbox that was checked. For an example if I check the "pending" checkbox, the data with the pending status gets displayed in the table. Below is a snippet of my checkboxes.

```js
<Grid align="left" direction="column" >
    <FormControlLabel
        value="all"
        control={
            <Checkbox 
                name="all" 
                id="all" 
                color="primary" 
                checked={ this.state.currentStatus === "all" }
                onChange={ this.statusChangeAction }
            />
        }
        label="All"
        labelPlacement="end"
    />
    <FormControlLabel
        value="pending"
        control={
            <Checkbox 
                name="pending" 
                id="pending" 
                color="primary" 
                checked={ this.state.currentStatus === "pending" }
                onChange={ this.statusChangeAction }
            />
        }
        label="Pending"
        labelPlacement="end"
    />
    <FormControlLabel
        value="in progress"
        control={
            <Checkbox 
                name="inProgress" 
                id="inProgress" 
                color="primary" 
                checked={ this.state.currentStatus === "inProgress" }
                onChange={ this.statusChangeAction }
            />
        }
        label="In Progress"
        labelPlacement="end"
    />
    <FormControlLabel
        value="dispensed"
        control={
            <Checkbox 
                name="dispensed" 
                id="dispensed" 
                color="primary" 
                checked={ this.state.currentStatus === "dispensed" }
                onChange={ this.statusChangeAction }
            />
        }
        label="Dispensed"
        labelPlacement="end"
    />
</Grid>
```

Currently I'm getting hard coded table data from a json file that I've created.

```js
<Grid container  direction="row">
    {patient.STATUS==="In Progress" && <img src={require("../../../../assets/images/icons/inprogress.svg")} alt="in_progress"  className="pharmacy-dashboard-status-icon-in-progress"/>}
    {patient.STATUS==="Pending" && <img src={require("../../../../assets/images/icons/pending.svg")} alt="pending"  className="pharmacy-dashboard-status-icon-pending"/>}
    {patient.STATUS==="Dispensed" && <img src={require("../../../../assets/images/icons/dispensed.svg")} alt="dispensed"  className="pharmacy-dashboard-status-icon-dispensed"/>}
</Grid>
```

These are my states

```js
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.handleSearch=this.handleSearch.bind(this);
        this.getSearchOption=this.getSearchOption.bind(this);
        this.handlePagination=this.handlePagination.bind(this);
        this.getPageCount=this.getPageCount.bind(this);
        this.statusChangeAction=this.statusChangeAction.bind(this);
        
        this.state={
            patientList: NurseOPDPatientData,
            filteredPatientList: NurseOPDPatientData,
            searchByList:SearchByList,
            filterByList:FilterByList,
            searchTerm: "",
            pageCount: 0,
            currentStatus: "all"
        }
    }
```

This is my function

```js
statusChangeAction(event){
        console.log(event.target.checked);
        const clickedId = event.target.id;
        const clickedStatus = event.target.checked;
        clickedStatus && this.setState({ currentStatus: clickedId });
        var currentFilteredPatientList = [];
         console.log(currentFilteredPatientList)
        this.state.patientList.map((singlePatient)=>{
            console.log(singlePatient);
            if((singlePatient.STATUS === clickedId) && clickedStatus){
                currentFilteredPatientList.push(singlePatient);
            }
        });
        console.log("currentFilteredPatientList", currentFilteredPatientList);
        this.setState({filteredPatientList: [...currentFilteredPatientList]});
        // this.setState({filteredPatientList: [...currentFilteredPatientList]});
    }
```

So basically, the checkboxes pending, in progress and dispensed works fine. But when I check the "All" checkbox after checking one of the other checkboxes I don't get any data. How do I fix that?

[image: Image of table after checkin the "All" checkbox]

Comment: In `statusChangeAction` when you filter `this.state.patientList`, maybe `clickedId` is not matching with any `singlePatient.STATUS` so the result is void. Correct?

Comment: Yes I've not set a STATUS called "all". So the result is void like you said @Giovanni

Comment: So, in case of `all`, take all the status (pending, inProgress and dispensed)!

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito would be great if you can explain how I should do it cus I'm sort of struggling with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on `statusChangeAction` when you filter `this.state.patientList`, in case of `clickedId === 'all'`. I would change your code like this:

```
statusChangeAction(event){
    console.log(event.target.checked);
    const clickedId = event.target.id;
    const clickedStatus = event.target.checked;
    clickedStatus && this.setState({ currentStatus: clickedId });
    var currentFilteredPatientList = [];
     console.log(currentFilteredPatientList)
    this.state.patientList.map((singlePatient)=>{
        console.log(singlePatient);
        if((singlePatient.STATUS === clickedId || clickedId === 'all') && clickedStatus) // in case of all get everything
        {
            currentFilteredPatientList.push(singlePatient);
        }
    });
    console.log("currentFilteredPatientList", currentFilteredPatientList);
    this.setState({filteredPatientList: [...currentFilteredPatientList]});
    // this.setState({filteredPatientList: [...currentFilteredPatientList]});
}
```